# Reusing XML elements for Rowsets vs semantic tagging

Tags: xml, xsd

We need to provide a webservice, which extracts row sets from a DB (Could be nested rows coming from a sub cursor).

Which ones below is a cleaner approach. I prefer the semantic approach though there might be advantages in using generic elements.

Option 1:

Reuse the "Row" element for each element that is a list. Might help automation (transform Row to a list on encountering). How would the XSD look like?

```
            <Data1 rows="2">
                <Row num="1"><Data11>Data</Data11></Row>
                <Row num="2"><Data11>Data</Data11></Row>
            </Data1>

            <Data2 rows="3">
                <Row num="1"><Data21>Data</Data21></Row>
                <Row num="2">                   
                    <Data3 rows="1">
                        <Row num="1">
                            <Data4>Data</Data4>
                            <Data5>Data</Data5>
                        </Row>
                    </Data3>
                </Row>
            </Data2>
```

Do not reuse elements. Maintain a semantic structure (Ignore the generalizations below, they will be replaced by meaningful elements)

```
            <Data1 rows="2">
                <Data1Row num="1"><Data11>Data</Data11></Data1Row>
                <Data1Row num="2"><Data12>Data</Data12></Data1Row>
            </Data1>

            <Data2 rows="3">
                <Data2Row num="1"><Data21>Data</Data21></Data2Row>
                <Data2Row num="2">
                    <Data3 rows="1">
                        <Data3Row num="1">
                            <Data4>Data</Data4>
                            <Data5>Data</Data5>
                        </Data3Row>
                    </Data3>
                </Data2Row>
            </Data2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would question your overall design. Whether you re-use the *Row* type or not, your design is still very restrictive and will make future change much more difficult.

Why not have the *Data* type also reusable?

The schema could then look like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://MySchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://MySchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MyRoot">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Data" type="Data" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <!-- Type definition: Data -->
  <xs:complexType name="Data" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Row" type="Row" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="rows" type="xs:int" />
  </xs:complexType>
  <!-- Type definition: Row -->
  <xs:complexType name="Row">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Data" type="Data" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="num" type="xs:int" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This would allow you to model a much wider variation of data structure.

**UPDATE**

Having read your below comments I would say do the opposite. You should be modelling each entity (person, city, etc) as a separate XSD complex type. Re-use is only of benefit if there is anything relevant to re-use, and I can't see that having a generic Row type which can actually represent many different things as a good candidate for re-use.

If you want me to expand this I am happy to do so.

Comment: Well, the Data1,2 etc were just generalizations. Most of them require semantic markup that map to meaningful nodenames.Eg. Data2Row should never appear under Data1.

Comment: But were you not considering standardising the *Row* type so you could re-use it? This means that Data2Row is just an instance of Row. So in theory it could go anywhere. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Consider this structure   <Person rows="2">
   <PersonRow num="1">
    <FirstName>Foo</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bar</LastName>
   </PersonRow>
   <PersonRow num="2">
    <FirstName>Foo2</FirstName>
    <LastName>Bar2</LastName>
   </PersonRow>
  </Person>
  <City rows="2">
   <CityRow num="1">
    <Name>Foo</Name>
    <ZipCode>22222</ZipCode>
   </CityRow>
   <CityRow num="2">
    <Name>Foo2</Name>
    <ZipCode>21222</ZipCode>
   </CityRow>
  </City>  WOuld you use PersonRow, CityRow or just use the Row type for both each of they might have unique children. Its not the best example though.

Comment: In that case I would completely change my recommendation. See update to my original answer above.